# Arguments to a decorator without using classes

Tags: python, class, python-decorators

```
def tracer(func, enabled=True):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if enabled:
            print('Calling {}'.format(func))
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrap


@tracer(enabled=False)
def rotate_list(l):
    return l[1:] + [l[0]]
```

I'm having a bit of confusion as to why this doesn't work, specifically this part: `@tracer(enabled=False)`

What I understand is happening here is: 
The function object `rotate_list` is passed as an argument whenever `tracer` performs a call.

I think the reason this doesn't work is because tracer(and any wrapper for that matter) only accepts callable objects, `enabled=False` isn't a callable so it doesn't work.

The error message however is not very indicative of that, so I'm wondering why the error message was:
`TypeError: tracer() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'`

I guess the arguments inside the parentheses were evaluated first, such that no callable object was passed to tracer?

I guess this can be solved by using class decorators, doing something like

```
class Trace:
    def __init__(self, enabled=False):
        print('Inside __init__')
        self.enabled = enabled
```

then `tracer = Trace(enabled=True)` would work, but I'd like to see how this can be solved without using classes.

============

EDIT (Solution):
Don't mind this, just typing it out to ensure I understood the solution.
Since placing an argument inside a decorator makes it act like a normal function. The solution would be to make that decorator return another callable object (which is the actual decorator).

Like:
`@dec`
`def foo: pass` would become `foo = dec(foo)`

`@dec(ARG)`
`def foo: pass` would become `foo = dec(ARG)(foo)`

The solution would be to make `dec` return another callable which is the actual decorator. For example that function would be `wrap`

`foo = dec(ARG)(foo)` would become `foo = wrap(foo)` where `ARG` was already passed to `dec`.
Thanks guys! I love functional programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done only with functions. `tracer` should look like this:

```
def tracer(enabled=False):
    def wrapper(func):
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            if enabled:
                print('Calling {}'.format(func))
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrap
    return wrapper
```

What is done here is that you created function (tracer) that returns decorator. That decorator accepts a function.

If you translate it to same format as python does for any decorator, you will see why this is required.

Every time python sees

```
@dec
def foo(): pass
```

it translates it to:

```
def foo(): pass
foo = dec(foo)
```

So, when you have decorator that requires arguments, it is translated like this:

```
foo = dec(ARGS)(foo)
```

So, what you need to do is make sure that decorator returns something that accepts function as its parameter.

PS: It is nice to use [functools.wraps](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) for decorator to preserve function name, docstrings, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

To pass other parameters than the function to a decorator-function you nest multiple defs:

```
def my_decorator(flagDoThat)
    def internal(func):
        def wrapper(*argv, **kwv):
            retval = func(*argv, **kwv)
            if flagDoThat:
                print("Hello", retval)
            return retval

        wrapper.__name__ = func.__name__ #update name
        return wrapper
    return internal

@my_decorator(True)
def my_func(): return "world"

#equals to

tmp = my_decorator(True)

@tmp
def my_func(): return "world"
```

### Edit

This decorator helps to build other decorators. While this contains multiple nested functions, it allows you to define decorators with only two layers and arguments, like you did:

```
def decorator(keepFunctionName=True):
    def internal(func):
        def newFunc(*argv, **kwv):
            def decoWrapper(theFuncUsedInFunc):
                fRet = func(theFuncUsedInFunc, *argv, **kwv)
                if keepFunctionName:
                    fRet.__name__ = theFuncUsedInFunc.__name__
                return fRet
            return decoWrapper
        return newFunc
    return internal
```

And can be used like this:

```
@decorator()
def my_decorator(func, flagDoThat):
    def wrapper(*argv, **kwv):
        retval = func(*argv, **kwv)
        if flagDoThat:
            print("Hello", retval)
        return retval

    return wrapper
```

And this decorator does exactly that what the decorator above does.

### Edit II

You can do the same thing with classes, by attaching the decorator to the init-function.

But here is an other way you can make decorators with parameters by storing them in classes:

```
class my_decorator:
    __slots__ = ["flagDoThat"] # optional line
    def __init__(self, flagDoThat):
        self.flagDoThat = flagDoThat

    def __call__(self, func):
        def wrapper(*argv, **kwv):
            retval = func(*argv, **kwv)
            if self.flagDoThat:
                print("Hello", retval)
            return retval

        return wrapper
```